# How to execute a query using @Query Spring JPA annotation

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am trying to write a query using SpringData Jpa using the @Query annotation on the interface method declaration.

The interface looks like this:

```
public interface MyService {

    @Query("select * from employee e where e.projectId = ?1")
    public List<Employee> getEmployeesWorkingOnAProject(String projectId) throws MyException;
}
```

I also have a class that implements this interface:

```
@Component
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {

}
```

I am not sure how will this query execution work and how to provide an implementation for getEmployeesWorkingOnAProject method in the imeplementing class.

Thanks

Comment: In this case, you don't need the `@Query`. Just name your method `findByProjectId(String)`, or even `findByProject(Project)` if you have a foreign-key relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Interface, you should **extend** JpaRepository (or any other spring data repository).
Then you can just **autowire** your interface in any spring bean class and call getEmployeesWorkingOnAProject().

So for example:

```
public interface MyService extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long> {

    @Query("select * from employee e where e.projectId = ?1")
    public List<Employee> getEmployeesWorkingOnAProject(String projectId) throws MyException;

}


@Component
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {

    private final MyService service;

    @Autowire // not necessary in spring 4.3 +
    public ProjectServiceImpl(MyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployeesWorkingOnAProject(String projectId) throws MyException {
         return service.getEmployeesWorkingOnAProject();
    }
}
```

However, Spring Data is able to build a query for you, so is no reason for writing your own query in this example.

**Spring Data way:**

```
public interface MyService extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long> {

    public List<Employee> findAllByProjectId(String projectId) throws MyException;

}
```

Comment: thnx. but what relationships do i need to define between employee and project so that this method name works.

Comment: I guess it's the different question, so you need to ask in new threat

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Your interface have to extend some kind of Spring Data Repository, for example [JpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html).

Second thing, in the Query annotation, you can put two types of query. JPQL or native SQL query. This can be controlled by a flag on the query annotation (nativeQuery).

In JPQL, your query should look like the following:

```
@Query("select e from employee e where e.projectId = ?1")
```